# Equivalent of .NET's MemoryMarshal in C++ (Arduino)?

Tags: c++, memory-management, casting, arduino, marshalling

I am new to Arduino and C++ development coming from C# so likely am missing so fundamental understanding. Kindly answer accordingly.

### Context

I am writing an Arduino sketch whereby I form a Http GET request in order to receive data from a Web API. In receiving the response, I am able to read the stream into `byte data[]` using `client.read(data,client.available())`. In my application, I know each `byte` represents a `char` in ASCII encoding. For processing of the response, I wish to convert this `byte[]` to a `char[]`, however this got me thinking...

### Question

How in C++ can I generically cast a `byte[]` to another known type without copying memory? In C# I would achieve this using the `MemoryMarshal`. Something tells me a I should be able to simply initialise an object from a pointer?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

byte is not a native C++ type, the Arduino environment creates it using a [typedef](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/is-uint8_t-equivalent-to-byte-etc/201618), it is actually a uint_8 (unsigned 8 bit integer) type. This is also the underlying type of a char, so you don't actually have to do anything. A byte array and char array are already the same data type, they're just labelled differently.

You could use a `(char)` cast to improve your code clarity, and this would not copy any data.

**Update:**

You can use a cast in C or C++ to tell the compiler to interpret some raw data as a different data type. In the example below, an array of 6 floats containing 2D vectors arranged XYXYXY, is cast to an array of 2D vector structures. This is done without any data being copies. However there are many pitfalls with this technique. You need be absolutely sure how the compiler is laying out the underlying storage of the structure. This is not defined by the standard so can vary between compilers, many will add padding for word alignment which will vary based on the architecture used. So use this method with care.

```
struct My2DVector {
    float x, y;
}

float flatVectorData[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.5, -5.0, 3.0};

// Cast the pointer to float to a pointer to My2DVector
My2DVector* structVectorData = (My2DVector*)flatVectorData;

printf("Vector 2 (%f %f)\n", structVectorData[1].x, structVectorData[1].y);
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you, that's certainly helpful in the case of my example. Specific to the "question" though, is there a generic approach to this? Imagine for example I had a `uint_8[6]` which was equivalent to a `myStruct[2]`, each `myStruct` having two fields of type `uint_8`. How is that type of cast approached? Again, without copies. Thanks

Comment: I've added an example which I hope makes sense

Comment: Perfect, thank you. That's as simple as I was expecting it to be but for someone reason or other couldn't find a clear answer. I also understand the risks of these operations without explicit memory management, thank you for that.